# Numerical output of RC Circuit

Tags: power-electronics, filter, matlab, math, integrator

I am trying to numerically generate the output voltage of an RC Filter to that of Plot 1 using the following formula.

[image]

Using the following code:

```
dt = 1e-6;
stop_time = 20e-3;
t = (0:dt:stop_time);
fin = 50;
w = 2 * pi * fin;
Vin = 10 * sin((w*t));

R = 100e+3;
C = 33e-9;
RC = R * C;

Vout = (1/RC) * Vin * dt ;
```

However this generates what is shown in Plot 2 which is a scaled down version of the input signal and is in phase.

What is the correct way to obtain the numerical results?

Thanks.

**Plot 1:**
[image: Circuit Sim]

**Plot 2:**

[image]

Edit 1:

Using Vout(n+1) = Vout(n)+((Vin(n))/RC) *dt
integrates (Plot 3) but does not generate the output voltage (Plot 1)

Plot 3:

[image]

Comment: You do the integration, which you haven't done, or know that the integral of sine is -cos

Comment: Your output formula is not for a lowpass RC. I'd recommend using Laplace. Start with \$H(s)=\frac{1}{sRC+1}\$ and \$V(s)=\frac{\omega^2}{s^2+\omega^2}\$, then apply inverse Laplace, see where it gets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is the so called [Forward-Euler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method) method of numerical integration. You have almost got it right, what you should do is make \$ V_{out} \$ a vector with the same number of points as the time vector, then loop over each index and do the approximate integration: $$ V_{out}(n+1) = V_{out}(n) + \frac{V_{in}(n)}{RC}\cdot dt$$

Comment: That method integrates the signal but does not generate the output voltage of Plot 1. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: @MXG123 This is the solution for your formula. But the formula is wrong. For an RC-filter it should be \$V_c=\frac{1}{RC}\int\left(V_{in}-V_{c}\right)dt\$

Comment: @AlexVB Thanks a mill. That did the trick.

Comment: How did the OP almost get it right when there is no integration in his code at all?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have integration in your code. A simple (not most precise) way to integrate is to use summation:

Vout = cumsum((1/RC) * Vin * dt);

**cumsum** is a cumulative summation function. Check its description on MATLAB site.